# Submitting a form via AJAX is making two calls instead of one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, backbone.js

I have an event listener for a form button that makes an AJAX call to a method in my Rails controller. The issue I'm having is that `this._form.submit()` is somehow making the AJAX call twice so in Chrome's Network tab, I see two `add_to_trip` calling being made.

I have tried removing `this._form.submit()` to see if there is code somewhere else that would be triggering this too, but upon removing, I see no AJAX call. I have also tried adding `console.log` to see how many times `__onTripClick` is being called. The `console.log` statement only fires off once.

Does anyone know why I am making two AJAX call even though I only click the selected target once?

Thanks.

```
$(document).on('click', this._formId + " a.trip", this, function (e) {
  e.data.__onTripClick(e);
});

__onTripClick: function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).attr('trip:id')) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
  this._toggling = $(e.target);
  this._form.children('input[name="id"]').first().val($(e.target).attr('trip:id'));
  this._form.submit();
},
```

Comment: What is `this` in the bigger context?

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and was removed in 1.9.

Comment: Have you tried extracting this method and testing it?

Comment: use `.on` instead of `.live` it is depreciated in jquery 1.9

Comment: even when using `.on`, it is still making two ajax calls. updated info

Comment: Do you have a `click` listener set up AS WELL AS an `onSubmit` listener? I don't see any Backbone.js code in your example. I'm kind of confused by the limited code that you're showing here.

Comment: I figured out why there were two calls. Found some code that was loading up some other JS file creating this bug. Thank you for the help!